# How to handle PHP files with Node.js HTML parser?

Tags: php, node.js, html-parsing, jsdom

I'm doing some modifications on HTML files with node.js. I'm using jsdom as the HTML parser (because parsing is more reliable than regexp), doing the modifications I need with jQuery and then passing the output to a file. Simple enough.

However, there is a problem when trying to handle PHP files. The parser output naturally chucks all the PHP code (as it's not HTML, as well as doctype, as it's not content), so I can't use the output directly anymore.

Any ideas how to parse and modify the HTML part and still keep the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The parser chucks all the PHP code, but you should be able to wrap those instructions in HTML comments to allow them to pass through the parser.